# android: styling ListView items from custom CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, coding-style, adapter, listviewitem

I have a custom CursorAdapter which I'm using to inflate a custom item layout and style accordingly, as shown in the code below.  My issue is that sometimes the wrong style information is supplied even though the data coming from the DB is correct (so for the below example I'll get `isEvent == true` but it'll go on to style as if `isEvent == false`.

Is this a known bug?  Am I doing something wrong or is there something I can do which will fix this?

```
private class EventAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public EventAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.event_view_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final boolean isEvent = cursor.getInt(EventQuery.IS_EVENT) == Event.EVENT;
        final String eventName = cursor.getString(EventQuery.NAME);
        final TextView eventNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_name);

        if (isEvent) {
            eventNameView.setText(eventName);
            view.findViewById(R.id.arrow).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.findViewById(R.id.in_play_icon).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            eventNameView.setText(cursor.getString(EventQuery.NAME));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a case of the old issue of Android reusing views.  By resetting the view and replacing where appropriate this can be fixed

Comment: Hi, How did you manage to stop android from recycling views?  I've been stuck with this problem for too long now...

Comment: Have a look at this http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html